# Database rows displayed in one line, not in separate <td>

Tags: html

I have set up a search bar on my php page but the results are all displayed in one long  in the table. How would I make it display search one of the results on a separate line, or maybe 2 on a line? Here is the code for the page.

```
<?php

    $names = array();

    if(isset($_POST['searchterm'])) {
        mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "Oliver");
        mysql_select_db("videos");

        $search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchterm']));

        $find_videos = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `videos` WHERE `keywords` LIKE'%$search%'");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_videos)) {
            $names[] = $row['name'];
        }

    }

    include('session.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="images/favicon.ico">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
  .vjs-default-skin .vjs-control-bar { font-size: 125% }
</style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Network TV | search</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link href="css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/3.1.1/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body style="overflow-x: hidden">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Network TV</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="\1\index.php">Home</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
        <section style="padding-top:100px; width:100%"class="container-fluid" id="section2">
                    <h1 class="text-center" style="color:white">Network TV</h1>
                <h3 class="text-center" style="color:white"><u>Search results</u></h3>



                                        <table class="table" style="color: white">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Username</th>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td><?php foreach($names as $name) { ?>
                                                        <td><?php echo $name; ?> <a href="http://www.google.com"><strong><h7><u>Watch!</u></h7></strong></a></td>
                                                        <?php } ?></td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
        </section>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Update**

[image: Result of updated code]
**Added updated picture**

[image]

Comment: td is a column, not a row.  This has nothing to do with php.

Comment: Sorry for that, il update the question, I thought because i'm editing in php its php. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting every result into the same `<tr>` and `<td>`, place them into multiple of them.

Looking at your HTML setup, I get the feeling you didn't quite grasp how the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags function. Remember that a `<tr>` (table row) adds a new row to the table, and inside that row you can place a `<td>` (table division), which functions as a column inside that row.
If that didn't explain it for you, perhaps one of these two resources will help you further: **[[1]](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm)** **[[2]](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/tables/article.php/3479851)**.

Inside your HTML, replace the `<tr>` block with the following:

```
<?php
foreach($names as $name) {
    echo '<tr>
        <td>' . $name . '</td>
        <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><strong><h7><u>Watch!</u></h7 </strong></a></td>
    </tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Updated code, see updated post for image, how do I fix this? thanks for the links too ill take a look

Comment: @OliverKetley As far as I understood your post, it currently looks how you wanted it to.
Could you please explain what exactly is still wrong?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I thought I included it, I want the table in the center, I added a new picture please look at it. Thanks.

Comment: Centering the table is no longer a problem related to PHP, and is instead related to CSS. Try Googling something along the lines of "CSS Center table", and enough results should pop up that will help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have extra `<td>` tag here

```
    <td><?php foreach($names as $name) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?> <a href="http://www.google.com"><strong><h7><u>Watch!</u></h7></strong></a></td>
    <?php } ?></td>
```

Try follwing and see if it aligns the result

```
    <?php foreach($names as $name) { ?>
    <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
    <td><a href="http://www.google.com"><strong><h7><u>Watch!</u></h7></strong></a></td>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I removed the extra tag. The code you gave does not change anything, but thanks for trying to help.